# Multiplication radio and select function doesn't work in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

For some reason this code doesn't work in Safari anyone have any clue to why?
The first radio box is fine but as soon as I check the second radio box it doesn't calculate. http://jsfiddle.net/njyEP/

Thanks

Javascript:

```
$("input[type=radio][name=radio],select").change(function() {

var radio = parseFloat($('#radio:checked').attr("tvalue")); 
var select = parseFloat($('#select').val());

$('#Total').text((select * radio)); 

});
```

html

```
<form method="post" action="">
<select name="select" id="select" name="select"><option value="1">1</option><option     value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option>
</select>

<div id="radioButtons"><input type="radio" class="multi" name="radio" id="radio" ivalue="1" tvalue="275" value="1185">Earlybird 1 Day Registration  $275<br>
<input type="radio" class="multi" name="radio" id="radio" ivalue="2" tvalue="475" value="1186">Earlybird 2 Day Registration  $475<br>
<input type="radio" class="multi" name="radio" id="radio" ivalue="3" tvalue="625" value="1187">Earlybird 3 Day Registration (all three days)  $625<br>
</div><div id="checkBoxes">

<br><label id="Total"></label><br></form>
```

Comment: For non-standard HTML attributes you should use the data-XXXXX notation like `data-tvalue`

Comment: Strange thing is this works in firefox and chrome. I wrote other part of the script using this method so  I hope I don't need to re-write everything again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't define multiple elements with the same id.
To make your example work in Safari, change your second javascript line to

```
var radio = parseFloat($('input[type=radio]:checked').attr("tvalue"));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2TCGp/

(Or, if you follow devnull69's advice and use data-tvalue, you can use jQuery's .data() method).

Comment: Yes got it thanks. What is the benefit using the data-tvalue method? data()

Comment: @Jangui See this question: [jQuery data vs attr?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr)

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that every id attribute on a page can only appear once. It is semantically illegal to provide the same id attribute to multiple elements